# boost::serialization of derived class from virtual base with no default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, radix, boost-serialization

I'm trying to serialize a derived class where the base has no default constructor. What I am doing so far is:

```
struct Data {
    int _value;
};

class Base;

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template<typename Archive>
    void save_construct_data(Archive&, const Base*, unsigned int);

    template<typename Archive>
    void load_construct_data(Archive&, Base*, unsigned int);
}}

class Base {
    Data& _ref;
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive&, unsigned int)
    {}

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    //friend load/save construct data, etc.
public:
    Base(Data& ref) : _ref(ref) {}
};
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(Base, boost::serialization::track_always);

//implementation of load/save construct data, etc

class Derived : public virtual Base {
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int)
    {
        //save / load construct data NOT CALLED!
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base);
    }
//other methods, etc
};
```

Above, the serialize() method of Base is called, which does nothing! Is there any way to have the save_construct_data or load_construct_data functions called from the derived class (without bypassing the serialization mechanism)? The whole point of this exercise is to track the memory locations of Base.

Thank you in advance.